# Is this old, possibly Musima classic guitar worth keeping?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, instruments, classical-guitar

I got a 1960-something Musima classic for 40 dollars on a flea market, I believe it is a classic (I can't find any information on the guitar anywhere, but it looks like a musima classic) but the fretboard is ripped up a bit and the tuning cogs are broken on the first string.

Is it worth it to restore or should I throw it away?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should really find a classical guitar player to give you an opinion - some old instruments are worth keeping (if hand made from good materials), some not.  Also don't "restore" until you are certain it's not of value to collectors - changing any of the original components may reduce the "value" to the collector types.  (I just googled "Musima guitar" and found lots of information about this brand.)

Comment: I would not trow away any wood that 56 years old.

Comment: Whether the wood is 56 or 100, if the guitar is not good, it's not good, no matter how much time you give the wood.
It will always be a 40 dollar guitar.

But I'll take it to an expert, thanks.

Comment: If it is Brazilian Rosewood it is worth a fortune regardless of the level of luthier work that made it.

Comment: After scouring the internet, I can only find ONE guitar with the same bridge. This old Ebay ad: https://www.google.dk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjVj9zc1-jKAhXCO5oKHQ98C84QjxwIAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.ebay.co.uk%2Fitm%2F231432021399%3F_mwBanner%3D1&bvm=bv.113370389,d.bGs&psig=AFQjCNFdol4AG-bfxzEfkaU7RN0ZDvBYqQ&ust=1455038704067446&cad=rja

Comment: Large picture of the other guitar. I can't tell the name, though: http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFg3NTA=/z/yvgAAOSwaNBUfikW/$_1.JPG

Answer (score 3):

From the pictures you've posted, it seems to be in good shape.  A lot(!) of scratches on the soundboard behind the bridge, but no obvious problems.

I can't be sure, but the soundboard (lighter wood on the top) seems to be solid timber all the way through - meaning it's possibly one-piece, better than the thin plywood like you get on more modern cheap guitars.

It has a zero-fret which is unusual (though note, this is not a bad thing); I've read this is often seen on older European-made guitars though I'm not an authority on that.  (Some people will tell you a zero fret is a bad thing - but that's a myth, they're fine if the setup is OK.)

It may be possible to replace the tuner - they're usually supplied as two plates with three on each, but the size and the distance between tuner shafts and between fixing screws sometimes varies, so if replacing it you should check the tuners against the guitar when buying...

So: I wouldn't know about any value to collectors (I'm not one) but if it plays OK I would certainly keep it.

One thing I'd look out for: it appears to be a classical-style guitar, but it looks like it's wearing steel strings.  These probably have higher tension than the more usual nylon-style strings fitted to classicals.  So if you tune this up or put new steel strings on, beware of putting too much tension on the bridge and soundboard.  (I'd recommend classical guitar strings if you want to replace the ones it's got.)

Comment: Yeah, the steel strings are the source of the bridge damage. If it has good tonal quality (put some new cheaper classical strings on it and see) and has a decent fretboard feel, then it probably should be taken for a quote to fix the basics (setup and bridge repair) at least. Then the decision is more "is it competitive with a new guitar at that price point?" Without even getting into collector status/desirability. I work in an antique {item} business and we prefer to get things untouched so we can put people we trust on the repairs. Something to think about

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the guitar it'd be hard to tell. It would cost quite a bit to fix the issues you mentioned. I think the best thing would be to take it to an expert and see if it's worth anything. Keep in mind that it could be simply a 40$ guitar.

Another thing to consider is its sound. Do you like it? If you do, you should repair it and keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Im a classical guitar player and yes it is in decent shape. But something music be done inorder to make it sellable 
a) if you do nothing but this FIX THE TUNING COGS without these functioning it renders the guitar basically useless
b) change the strings they are old and worn out also, they are not for classical guitar. The steel strings will cause extra tension on the fretbpard causing it to spoil pretty quickly

If it is a solid top guitar you are in luck. Solid top guitars sound better the longer you play them for due tp the vibrations you create by playing the strings. If you have been playing it should make your guitar sound much better. The fretboard is just pointless to repair it playable it will do for a newby/intermediate. Many people are often concerned about the appearance of a guitar. These are not lacquer cracks but actual dents and scratches in the wood you could easily fill them in. You may get a bit more for the guitar. Do not get a proffessial to do it they will charge a fair amount and looking at how much you could make it may not be worth it. Do it yourself and if you screw it up oh well. 
Good luck!
Source : 9+yrs playing the classical guitar

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, musima is an old, not more operating manufacterer from the so called 'Deutsche Demokratische Republik / DDR' - German Democratic Republic. I got one by myself. The guitars are nothing special, excluded their historical value for some people i guess.